# How to use dynamic local image in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm trying to show dynamic images depending on a selected option (using the template shown below), but when I deploy the app, I think Webpack changes the image filename. How can I prevent this renaming?

```html
<select v-model="geturl">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div v-if="geturl">
    <img
        :src="require(`@/assets/images/${geturl}.jpg`)"
        style="height:250px; width:250px; object-fit:cover;">
</div>
```

If I change the options in dev mode, I can see the images; but when I deploy the app, the image filename converts to `1.zxc123.jpg`.

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Webpack changes the names of the image assets it processes but that's why you used `require`, in order to get that changed name.  The bundle also contains that name so be sure to use the bundled files in production

Comment: use images as static files instead of `assets` which will be processed by webpack

Comment: @AlexHunter But this is already correct, why change it?

Comment: @AlexHunter what I means this that you should not let webpack processed your images, because the files will be processed to files which is proper for transportion (depends on its size). For server side render vue (maybe you are not, but it doesn't matters), files in asset folder will be processed by node, but files in static folder will not be proceesed. Consider images as an ordinary file like `robot.txt` or `favicon.ico`.[more about it](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/static)

Comment: because it wont work, im building a library (npm run build-lib), when i install it, console say image not found  @Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images written to the output directory are handled by the [`file-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) (via the [`url-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/)). Vue CLI configures the `file-loader` with a [filename template](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#template-strings) of:

```
'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
```

In your [Vue project config](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js), remove `.[hash:8]` from the filename template to disable the asset hash:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('images')
        .use('url-loader')
          .loader('url-loader')
          .tap(options => {
            // file-loader is the fallback loader
            options.fallback.options.name = 'img/[name].[ext]'
            return options                             
          })
  }
}
```

Comment: @vineeth The OP doesn't have use for the hash (and probably no need for caching), and explicitly *wants* to remove the hash because it prevents usage of the library.

Comment: Yes. I just read the above comment. Thanks. Yes removing hash is a good solution for this problem

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent the renaming by simply moving your images to `public` folder and use absolute paths in the component to import the images.

Then you can use like..

```
<img :src="`${geturl}.jpg`">
```

OR if you want to better control the base_url then you can do something like below..

In public/index.html, you need to prefix the link with `<%= BASE_URL %>`:

```
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

In templates, you will need to first pass the base URL to your component:

```
data () {
  return {
    publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}
```

Then:

```
<img :src="`${publicPath}${geturl}.jpg`">
```

Comment: The OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65743127/how-to-use-dynamic-local-image-in-vue/65785656#comment116250951_65743127) that they're building the project as a library, so static assets is not a viable option.

Comment: Ahh sorry, didn't notice that. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the image in the public/images (images need to be created) directory, because it will not be compiled by webpack. vue2 is placed in the static/images directory. If you don't want to do this, then you need to require to import the image, because then you can get the correct image path after webpack is compiled.

Example:

```
...
  data: {imgs: [require('../assets/images/1.png'),require('../assets/images/1.png')]}
...
```

Comment: It is not recommended to delete the webpack loader hash, because it will easily cause caching. When you replace the image, it cannot be updated faster. Lead to the display of old image content.